# ARKit view controller and renderer specialization depending user input

Tags: swift, arkit

I'm currently working on an app containing 2 view controllers. The first one is a simple screen with 3 buttons and the second one is an ARSCNView.

When the user click on a button, the app opens the second view controller (ARSCN View). In this ARView I have to do lot of stuff in a renderer depending on which button the user clicked. I also load different assets and process depending on the button clicked. But also lot of commun code and UI in the rest of the controller, that why I didn't divide the code in different view controllers. So currently I have an if else section in the renderer like that :

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willRenderScene scene: SCNScene,atTime time: TimeInterval)  {
   if button1 { 
        //do lot of stuff here
        //specific asset and process
   } else if button2 {
        //do lot of stuff different
        //specific asset and process 
   } else if button3 { 
        //doing something also different 
        //specific asset and process
   } else {
        //raise error
   }
}
```

My question is how to do that more cleaner and having something scalable if I have more button in the future. I really want something clean (maybe is the cleanest way as it it now). I checked stuff but I'm not able to determine which is the best. I investigated on that:

- Strategy pattern but not sure if I can apply it here.
- Protocol but I don't know how to integrate it in my use case
- inheritance from ARView

Do you have any clues on how can manage that ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) seems like the way to go here.

Create a `BaseViewController` class that creates/manages the ARSCNView and handles all of the shared work between the 3 experiences invoked by those buttons.  Then create 3 other ViewController classes, e.g. `Button1ViewController`, `Button2ViewController` etc. that subclass your new base controller:

```
class Button1ViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willRenderScene scene: SCNScene,atTime time: TimeInterval)  { 
        // Do the button 1 work here
    }
}
```

You can override any method necessary for your individual experiences. If the base class also needs to run code in those delegate methods, you can call `super.renderer(...)` from within your overrides to invoke the base controller method.